# Why is this loop bad practice?

Tags: java, loops, coding-style

The following loop is not good practice. Is it due to a `String` being the main condition of the `for` loop rather than an `int` variable, meaning the `for` loop is infinite? Also, is it due to there being no instance to enter 'end' to stop the loop?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
for (String s = in.next(); !s.equals("end"); i++) 
{
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

How can I rewrite it, so that it conforms to accepted style?

(This is a question in a past exam paper.)

Comment: it's not as much a bad practice as an infinite loop ...

Comment: "accepted style" is refering to any specific set of standards?

Comment: @ericbn http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: A good way to see what really happens is to break it down into a while loop, you are mixing scanner loop logic with your own business logic. Separate them.

Comment: I would say the question as stated does not have an answer because the code in the given state can't be analyzed as a solution. It isn't correct code. Whether the solution is "good practice" or not depends on how it looks by the time you actually *have* a working solution.

Comment: *"Also that there is no instance to enter 'end' to stop the loop?"* Bingo.

Comment: I feel sorry for students that have to deal with such poorly designed questions and assignments.

Comment: Perhaps this should go to codereview beta?

Answer (score 39):

Well your string `s` is never changing, which can lead to an infinite loop. You probably wanted:

```
for (String s = in.next(); !s.equals("end"); s = in.next(), i++) {
    ...
}
```

Some (me included) might say that `i++` shouldn't be in the increment section of this loop, since it's not directly relevant to the condition:

```
for (String s = in.next(); !s.equals("end"); s = in.next()) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

---

> Is it due to a string being the main condition of the for loop rather than an int variable, meaning the for loop is infinite?

The original loop was indeed infinite (at least, after an initial input is entered and assuming `"end"` wasn't the first input). However, it's not for the reason you state. For-loops *are* most commonly written using integral loop control variables, but it's not always the case. For example, a common idiom for iterating through a linked list is:

```
for (Node node = list.head; node != null; node = node.next) {
    ...
}
```

The problem with your loop is that the string `s` is never changed, so it will never equal `"end"` unless that's the first input.

Comment: and even then, you'll need to be sure that whatever it's looping against will always at some point have "end" as a value, otherwise it will infinite loop.

Comment: `for (String s; !(s = in.next()).equals("end");)` does away with the duplication.

Comment: Marko: and also does away with readabilty…

Answer (score 34):

I would suggest separating the looping condition and the call to `Scannner.next()`:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.next();
    if (s.equals("end")) {
      break;
    }
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered " + s);
    i++;
}
```

I think this is much easier to understand than trying to squeeze everything into a `for` expression.

Comment: I'm going to side with this one. a `while` loop _is_ better practice for a loop with an unknown iteration length.

Comment: Yes, this is much clearer than the solutions trying to cram all logic into one boolean expression.

Comment: @peeskillet I can't say I agree with that. Yes, for-loops generally do have a known iteration length, but using one that does not isn't necessarily bad practice if it is used correctly. Indeed, what the OP has here *is* a valid use case for a for-loop: a clear initialization, a related condition and a related increment step. Indeed, there are other common cases where for-loops don't have a known iteration length; I touch upon this briefly in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple problems with this code:

1. `s` never changes after the initial assignment, so it's an infinite loop.
2. Calling `.next()` could throw `NoSuchElementException` or `IllegalStateException`.  Rather than catching these exceptions, I consider it more polite to check `.hasNext()` beforehand, since running out of input is a foreseeable rather than an exceptional situation.  However, the alternative ask-for-forgiveness style could also be acceptable.
3. The for-loop header does not form a coherent story — it initializes `s` and tests `s`, but updates `i`.
4. In my opinion, `System.out.format()` would be slightly more preferable to `System.out.println()` with concatenation.

I would write it as:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
String s;
while (in.hasNext() && !"end".equals(s = in.next())) {
    System.out.format("The value of i is: %d and you entered %s\n", i++, s);
}
```

It might also be a nice user interface touch to tell the user that `end` is a magic word to terminate the loop (assuming it were modified to work as probably intended).

Comment: That while-condition is not very readable. It’s better to keep it as while(in.hasNext()) and keep the rest of the logic in the loop body.

Comment: @Petter I find it readable enough. I prefer it to @andersschuller's solution, where `while (in.hasNext())` only tells part of the story. Here, the condition accurately describes how the loop should terminate.

Answer (score 4):

The common practice with for loops is that the counter variable is repeated in each term:

```
for(int i=...; i<... ; i++)
```

In the example above, the code mixes variables. Which is confusing to the reader and probably lead to the bug that the loop only terminates if you input `end` as the first value.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a good idea because the string `s` may never equal `"end"`. You'll probably want to check if the scanner has another string. Also, you only initialize the string to `in.next()` but you need to set `s` to the next string after each iteration of the loop.

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
  String s = in.next();
  if (s.equals("end")) {
    break;
  }
  // ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This loop is a bad idea, because you're taking setting `s` once from the user input and not in every iteration.
Thus, it will cause you to run infinite time in case `s` was filled with value different from "end".

You probably wanted something more like this:

```
for (String s; (s = in.nextLine()).equals("end"); i++) 
{
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach is too bad.

The Given Code :-

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
for (String s = in.next(); !s.equals("end"); i++) 
{
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

The 1st part of for loop only execute once in life.

```
String s = in.next() //Execute only once in life
```

The 2nd part of this for loop never be true , because the input console will never allow to enter the 2nd input.

```
!s.equals("end")//2nd part
```

This program will never allow to enter 2nd input from console, because the `in.next()` will execute only once.And the exit token for this loop is "end" which is not possible to enter after first input.

This type of loops should be implemented by while loop .

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNext()){
String yourdata=in.next();
if(yourdata.equals("end")){
//Stop the loop 
}
//Do you code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It bad practice because it's terminated only if next obtained token is "end". It does'n not consider situation like. e.g. end of input stream.

So when then stream ends and nowhere along "end" appeared you'l get `s=null` and `NullPointerException` at `s.equals("end")`.

You can correct it e.g. by changing condition to `in.hasNext() && !"end".equals(s)`.

Also s is never changing after it was initialized.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "why rewrite it" the answer is basically as others have pointed out, that it's currently an infinite loop, and also that it's not very readable as it stands.  Personally I'd rewrite it as a while loop, which several others have already pointed out how to do, as it makes your intentions a little more clear than a for loop with a counter that's counting up to infinity.  Someone unfamiliar with how the code is supposed to work could easily confuse an infinite increment to be an oversight by the programmer who wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

The string s is never modified. The loop never ends. What about this :

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; !s.equals("end"); i++) {
        s = in.next();
        System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered "
                + s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned that the loop does not end because you are not changing the value of s, so the loop never ends. This may be what your professor intended, and it may not be. Bad code is bad practice, as a rule, but there are other reasons why this is bad practice.

What jumped out to me as being bad practice here, and what the professor could have intended, is the use of a `for` loop here. As my professor told me, "For loops are for when you know when you want the code to end, while loops are for when you don't know when you want the code to end." So if you have an iterable `i` such as this code:

```
for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

In this code, you know that you want to iterate i from 0 to 100. A `while` loop is what you would want to use in the situation your professor is discussing.

```
int counter;
while(*(str+counter))
    counter++;
```

You have no idea when the loop is going to end, because you don't know how long the `str` is, but you know that sometime it will get to the null pointer, and the loop will terminate. This generally what is best practice.

So for the code your professor posted, you may want it to look like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
while(!s.equals("end"))
{
    i++;
    String s = in.next();
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

Comment: “As my professor told me” – In languages like Java, your professor is pretty objectively wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Is there an explanation that goes with that or what?

Comment: I thought it was obvious from context: it contradicts established best practices. Using `for` loops in certain situations where you can’t prove the bound statically is an established idiom in Java. And since the only argument *against* doing so would be convention, this argument doesn’t hold.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I guess they told me that for C, and it was mirrored in my python book as well. Having taken Java before C or python, it made sense to me that the logic would hold true for Java as well. Many others in this thread are saying much the same thing, that a `while` loop would be better suited to this. What situations are you talking about where you can't prove the bound statically?

Comment: But the same is absolutely true for C – in fact, that’s where Java got the habit from. And a `while` loop  might be better suited *in this particular* situation. That’s different from what you’re saying (and consequently I don’t see anybody else agreeing with you). `for (Iterator i = something.iterator(); i.hasNext();)` is such an idiomatic use, as is `for (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); in.hasNext();)`. Python is a completely different case because Python’s `for` loops function differently.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is bad practice, because there isn't any need for a `for` loop. In this case, I believe it's useless. It could be just this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.next();
if (!s.equals("end"))
{
    System.out.println("You have enetered" + s);
}
```

See, there isn't any need for a loop. The loop you had was making things more complicated than they had to be. I was always think that things should be kept as simple as they can be unless they require complexity. `For` loops are only to be used when you have more than one action that you want the code to do. In the case above, only one thing is happening: the `println` statement, so there's no need for a loop. It's unnecesary...

Also, the loop never ends. So there's that too, but that's just faulty code. That's not why it's bad practice. It's bad practice because of the unnecesary use of a `for` loop. It's also faulty, because the code is wrong. So there are two different things going on with this code.

Comment: Yes there is need for a loop. It is supposed to repeatedly accept input and print it *until* the input is "end".

Answer (score 1):

It is not in good practice because of two things:

1. for loops are meant to iterate over a collection of data
2. a for loop consists of iterator initial state, loop condition and an iterating function that are *related*

The `for` statement just intermixes two different information (the stream and the counter).  Even if it *does work*, it isn't good practice to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would have just left a comment, but I don't have the rep yet.
What I haven't seen explained is WHY your s value is not changing.

In a typical **for** loop:

```
for(a=1; a<=10; a+=1) {body}
```

the initial phrase, 'a=1', is ONLY performed once as an initialization.

the third phrase, 'a+=1', is performed once at the end of every cycle, until…

the second phrase, 'a>=10', evaluates false.

so a **for** loop would be represented in 'psuedo-code' something like this:

```
    a=1         // first phrase
:LoopLabel
    {body}
    a+=1        // third phrase
    if (a<=10)  // second phrase (boolean evaluation)
        then goto LoopLabel
```

Likewise, your example, in similar pseudo-code might look like this:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    String s = in.next()
:LoopLabel
    {
        System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i + " and you entered " + s);
    }
    ++i
    if (!s.equals("end"))
        goto LoopLabel
```

So the reason your program was an infinite loop was the value of 's' was only set on entry to your loop and never changed during each loop execution, as most likely desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; in.hasNext(); i++) {
    String s = in.next();
    if (s.equals("end")) {
        break;
    }
    ...
```

Endless loop, or no loop (when s is initially "end").

Comment: This would look much cleaner in a `while` loop

Comment: I still see no reason using a for loop rather a while loop. Do you agree and have just rewritten the for loop to work?

Comment: I did that (without much conviction) to limit the scope of `i`. A while seems indeed more regular, as the for-parts are not entirely coherent.

Answer (score 0):

A number of responses above are correct to say that what you've written is an infinite loop. But I wanted to clarify *why* this is an infinite loop. The **for** loop you're using differs from the other form you may be thinking of:

```
String[] stringArray = { "1", "2", "3" };
for (String s : stringArray) {
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

In that case, the variable **s** is initialized with the next value from your collection or array on each iteration. But that form of **for** loop works with collections and arrays and can't be used with iterators like the **Scanner** class.

The form of **for** loop you're using differs in that the initialization clause (where you have `String s = in.next()`) is called *ONLY* the first time through the loop. **s** is set that first time, then never changed.

You could re-write like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (String s = in.next(); !s.equals("end"); s = in.next()) {
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i++ + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

But another bad thing in here is that there's no null or end check. It's conceivable if not likely that you would run out of strings before you found one that equaled "end". If that happened, then the **for** test clause (the middle one) would give you a **NullPointerException** when it tried to the call to the **equals()** method. THAT is definitely bad practice. I would probably re-write this like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.next();
    if (s.equals("end")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i++ + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

If you really want a **for** loop instead of a **while**, it would be better to do this:

```
int i = 0;
for (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); in.hasNext();) {
    String s = in.next();
    if (s.equals("end")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i++ + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

One last variation that preserves the test against the string in the test clause would look like this:

```
int i = 0;
String s = "";
for (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     in.hasNext() && !s.equals("end"); 
     s = in.next()) {
    System.out.println("The value of i is: " + i++ + " and you entered " + s);
}
```

You could also add a null check in there before the `s.equals("end")` for total safety.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good practice maybe because you are comparing the `String s` with a String but you are not comparing the value, you are comparing the memory position of the `s` value.

Comment: There is no memory position comparison, it is a normal "equals" comparison, which will compare the content for strings.